# How do I move my Button and Edittext freely in android studio

Tags: android-studio

So I have 3 fields to get user input from and a button. When i try to move them the "centerinParent = true" inserts automatically even when i turn it off. I want to move those fields where I want (I use relative layout) and they just wont move What should I do?

activity code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numar_secunde_work"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="nr secunde workout"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="236dp"
    android:text="Start Workout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numar_repetitii"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="249dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="nr repetitii"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numar_pauza"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="191dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="nr secunde pauza"
    android:inputType="number" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: awwww...hard to understand what specifically you're trying to do, can you please elaborate a little bit more? Like...what are you trying to accomplish, what have you tried. These are some good points on [how to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please briefly explain your problem with additional java+layout code and also with pictures or even videos depending on the problem

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Have you tried using ContraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout ? RelativeLayout by default takes vertical format and align the childs from top to bottom and for horizontal it aligns the childs from left to right. For your case, you should try using ContraintLayout

Comment: Thank you !!! this solved my problem